# How to import Android library project in Android Studio RC 2

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, libraries

I have a bit stupid question..

I am trying to import android library project in AS rc 2 and first step in every tutorial is create directory called "libraries" in root of project. But: I dont know how to do that in Android Studio RC 2.. I just may create "module" or "Android resource directory"... But I need "directory"... If I create this directory out of Android Studio, the AS don't show that in the project.. Plz help me. Or tell me other way to import android library project. I need this: https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce your directory problem, but what I would do:

1. In Project Toolbar (Alt+1) place cursor on your module and press Alt+Insert -> Directory -> create a folder for your libraries (doesn't matter how you name it in general)
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S for Project Structure -> choose your module -> "Dependencies" tab -> Alt+Insert -> File Dependency -> Choose your new library -> OK

Comment: I'm on RC4 now, but I have used RC2 as well and don't recall any significant changes with relation to your issue.

Comment: Did it help or do you still have the problem?

Comment: sorry. i'm in a bed and going to sleep. in my country is 11:09 pm and tomorrow i go to school